# Is there an idiomatic way to parse JSON into objects with a shared base class but differing data shapes?

Tags: dart

I'm brand new to Dart so I've just been getting my feet wet implementing an SDK for an existing API,
but I'm running into some issues figuring out how to structure things to cut down on boilerplate when
I'm parsing the responses from the server.

Basically, all responses from the API look like the following:

```json
{
  "data": {
    ...
  },
  "error": {
    ...
  }
}
```

where either `data` or `error` is present, but never both. Fairly standard stuff. The shape of the
`error` isn't all that interesting since it's the same for every response, but the `data` object is
different for every response. So far I've been able to get something "working" by declaring a base class
that handles the error and passing that up through `super` (I should note I'm using the
`json_serializer` package):

```dart
class Response {
  Response({this.error});

  Error? error;
}

@JsonSerializable(createToJson: false)
class ExampleResponse extends Response {
  ExampleResponse({
    this.data,
    Error? error,
  }) : super(error: error);

  Map<String, dynamic>? data;

  factory ExampleResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExampleResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

This works but I lose all of the type information for the `data` field. I'm not sure how to approach this
from here that doesn't involve yet another class for the data shape:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Thing {
  Thing(this.name);

  String name;

  factory Thing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ThingFromJson(json);

  String toString() => 'Thing{name: $name}';
}

@JsonSerializable()
class ExampleResponseData {
  ExampleResponseData(this.thing);

  Thing thing;

  factory ExampleResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExampleResponseDataFromJson(json);

  String toString() => 'ExampleResponseData{thing: $thing}';
}

@JsonSerializable(createToJson: false)
class ExampleResponse extends Response {
  ExampleResponse({
    this.data,
    Error? error,
  }) : super(error: error);

  ExampleResponseData? data;

  factory ExampleResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExampleResponseFromJson(json);

  String toString() => 'ExampleResponse{error: $error, data: $data}';
}
```

In Go I would just define an inner struct for occassions where the type has no value outside of JSON
parsing like:

```golang
type ExampleResponse struct {
    Error *Error `json:"error"`
    Data *struct {
        Thing Thing `json:"thing"`
    } `json:"thing"`
}
```

but I'm a lot rustier with OOP in general and on even more unfamiliar ground with Dart. Is there a
better way to handle this that doesn't end up with twice as many types as there are responses?

Comment: Is json_serializable strict requirement for you, or you can consider other options like https://pub.dev/packages/built_value ?

Comment: I would say that at this point I don't have any strict requirements other than the shape of the API response. When I initially looked at both libraries, `built_value` seemed more boilerplate-y, but I don't have a good enough sense of either to know whether it would be better or worse given my current issue.

Comment: Will you have different "data" type on same endpoint, or you will know what data type to expect on given endpoint ?

Comment: Endpoints always return the same data shape. In general terms, the API is designed as a pseudo-RPC service where every endpoint has a known request and response format, but responses are all transformed in an identical fashion. Error returns are transformed and used to populate the `error` field, non-error returns are put under the `data` field but remain otherwise unchanged. So in the example above, a call to the fictional `/Example` endpoint always returns a `Thing` which is marshaled into the `thing` field inside of the `data` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution based on built_value. Idea is to use generic for data type. Built value can handle such cases, though you will have a little bit of boilerplate. Below you can find example:

```dart
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';

part 'built_value_example.g.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final resultAJson = endpointA();
  final resultA = serializers.deserialize(resultAJson, specifiedType: FullType(Response, [FullType(DataA)]));
  print(resultA);

  final resultBJson = endpointB();
  final resultB = serializers.deserialize(resultBJson, specifiedType: FullType(Response, [FullType(DataB)]));
  print(resultB);
}

Map<String, dynamic> endpointA() {
  final data = DataA((b) => b..dataAField = 7);
  final response = Response<DataA>((b) => b..data = data);
  return serializers.serialize(response, specifiedType: FullType(Response, [FullType(DataA)])) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}

Map<String, dynamic> endpointB() {
  final data = DataB((b) => b..dataBField = 'data b value');
  final response = Response<DataB>((b) => b..data = data..error = 'data b error');
  return serializers.serialize(response, specifiedType: FullType(Response, [FullType(DataB)])) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}

abstract class Response<DATA_TYPE> implements Built<Response<DATA_TYPE>, ResponseBuilder<DATA_TYPE>> {
  Response._();

  factory Response([Function(ResponseBuilder<DATA_TYPE> b) updates]) = _$Response<DATA_TYPE>;

  static Serializer<Response> get serializer => _$responseSerializer;

  DATA_TYPE get data;

  String? get error;
}

abstract class DataA implements Built<DataA, DataABuilder> {
  DataA._();

  factory DataA([Function(DataABuilder b) updates]) = _$DataA;

  static Serializer<DataA> get serializer => _$dataASerializer;

  int get dataAField;
}

abstract class DataB implements Built<DataB, DataBBuilder> {
  DataB._();

  factory DataB([Function(DataBBuilder b) updates]) = _$DataB;

  static Serializer<DataB> get serializer => _$dataBSerializer;

  String get dataBField;
}

@SerializersFor([
  DataA,
  DataB,
  Response,
])
final Serializers serializers = (_$serializers.toBuilder()
      ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
      ..addBuilderFactory(FullType(Response, [FullType(DataA)]), () => ResponseBuilder<DataA>())
      ..addBuilderFactory(FullType(Response, [FullType(DataB)]), () => ResponseBuilder<DataB>()))
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have to find some time to dig in to get a better sense of how this all works, but I appreciate you taking the time.